# Python global variables aren't working in a loop

Tags: python

```
i=-1
while True:
    global i
    ++i
    if i>5:
        break
    print i
```

I want it to print `0 1 2 3 4`, but it prints `0 0 0` all the time. How do I fix this?

Comment: Python has no `++` operator.

Comment: why are you using a global in the first place?

Comment: `++i` is the same as `+(+(i))` in Python; it is the application to two unary-plus operators and does not reassign to `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the variable `i`

```
i=-1
while True:
    global i
    i+= 1 #<----- 
    if i>5:
        break
    print i
```

Comment: Not even any need for the global keyword here: i is a local variable, while does not introduce a scope.

Comment: hehe, this still doesn't give the desired results, you set `i` to -1 at the start so it prints from 0 to 5, not from 1 to 5 as requested in question, set it to 0 to fix :)

Comment: @W1ll1amvl Take a look at the question again. It does request 0 to 5.

Comment: question says "i want it to print `1 2 3 4 5`", the answer you gave solves problem, but also prints 0 at the start of the list.

Comment: @AHuman oh I see question has now changed, it asks to print `0 1 2 3 4`, but your way still gives an extra 5 at end of list, **not that it matters as such**, but you could just change the if statement to `if i>4:`!

Answer (score 0):

```
i=-1
def test():
    while True:
        global i
        i+=1
        if i>=5:
            break
        print i

test()
```

Thanks everyone helped me.